# Angular Http Call map Api Response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I'd like to get my trips, which are my response from API in Angular.

From the backend I'm getting:

```
{
  "trips": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "startDate": "2019-06-30T06:05:48.006Z",
      "endDate": "2019-06-30T06:05:48.006Z",
      "description": "string",
      "roomSharing": true,
      "countries": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "code": "string"
        }
      ],
      "languages": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "code": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which is fine, but I have a problem on the client side.
Here's my code for getting trips:

```
  getTrips(): Observable<Trip[]> {
    return this.http.get<Trip[]>(this.apiUrl + '/Trip/Get')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('fetched trips')),
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError),
        map(data => {
          return data;
        })
      );
  }
```

and in my component I have:

```
  loadTrips() {
    return this.rest.getTrips()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.trips = data;
      console.log(this.trips);
    }
    , err => console.log(err));
  }
```

I'd like to get trips in a template like:

```
<div class="card mb-3 trip" *ngFor="let trip of trips">
```

but I have to like:

```
<div class="card mb-3 trip" *ngFor="let trip of trips.trips">
```

So, the question is how can I map my response to get Trip array instead of Array of Trips array?

Comment: If `trips` has a `trips` property, then it's not `Trip[]`. If you start with an interface that actually represents the data, and type the return value of loadTrips, the compiler can be a lot more help. I'd suggest enabling the TS strict mode to prevent implicit any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this should work:

```js
  interface TripsResponse {
    trips: Trips[],
  }
```

```js
  getTrips(): Observable<Trip[]> {
    // use your response interface instead
    //return this.http.get<Trip[]>(this.apiUrl + '/Trip/Get')
    return this.http.get<TripsResponse>(this.apiUrl + '/Trip/Get')
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log('fetched trips')),
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError),
        map(data => {
          return data.trips; // set it properly here
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I have no warnings like 'Property 'trips' does not exist on type 'Trip[]'.' ? Now, I'm getting ERROR in src/app/trips-list/trips-list.component.ts(23,25): error TS2339: Property 'trips' does not exist on type 'Trip[]'.

Comment: See my updated answer, and set it there instead of in my initial post.

Comment: You must remove the `<Trip[]>` in the `get` request, as shown in my most recent answer update, or create a new data structure that matches what your API returns.

Comment: @jkniotek I'm still getting ERROR in src/app/services/rest.service.ts(35,23): error TS2339: Property 'trips' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Something along the lines of my most recent update should work... I will check again when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

Dont over complicate by doing `.map`, just do:

```
 loadTrips() {
    return this.rest.getTrips()
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.trips = data.trips;
    }
    , err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Also, correct the model `Trip[]` which you have created it should be

```
export interface ITripsResponse {
    trips: Trips[],
  }
```

`return this.http.get<ITripsResponse>(this.apiUrl + '/Trip/Get')`

> or else, correct `.map` by

```
    map((data) => {   
      return data.trips; 
    })
```

and then `Observable<Trip[]>` would be a valid return type

Answer (score 1):

Change your return statement:

```
return this.http.get('/Trip/Get')
  .pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log('fetched trips')),
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.handleError),
    map((data: TripsResponse) => {   // change made here; make data of type TripsResponse 
      return data.trips; 
    })
  );
```

where TripsResponse is

```
interface TripsResponse {
   trips: Trips[],
   ... // other fields for future if required
}
```

Comment: I personally think it's the way to go... (+1)

Comment: Haha. Thanks Ploppy!

Comment: Absolutely Not +1  :D

Comment: Appreciate that @Shashank!